# Problem with fraction

Tags: fractions

I have a problem with the appearance of a fraction which has in its numerator another fraction. It is not very beautiful as the second fraction is small, even though I use `\displaystyle`. How can I have both fraction as big as they should be? And why this is happening even though I use `\displaystyle`?

Thanks!

The code I use is like this:

```
$\displaystyle \frac{\frac{a}{b}-c}{d}$
```

Comment: use `\cfrac`—it's meant for continued fractions and will keep the size sane.  (for this though (only two levels deep), i'd recommend-ish against it.  there are generally reasons these decisions were made.)

Comment: I guess `\frac` sets `\textstyle` for its contents.

Comment: Thanks but if I want for example to have 3 or 4 fractions the one in the other's numenator what should I do?

Comment: where is `\fraction` defined? (it isn't defined in any packages I know) Please _always_ provide a complete document that shows the problem, that way it is obvious what packages are being used.

Comment: Sorry I meant \frac{}{}!

Comment: @Adam That's another reason why you should always post a complete (tested) document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using

```
$\displaystyle \cfrac{\cfrac{a}{b}-c}{d}$
```

should sort you out.  The `cfrac` macro (from the `amsmath` package) is for **c**ontinued **frac**tions.

[image]

Comment: Use `\dfrac`, not `\cfrac`.

Comment: @egreg Considered that, but wouldn't that tend to look strange with 3–4–5-level deep fractions?  Does `\cfrac` do things that are specific to continued fractions and aren't applicable to other things?  (thumbs through `amsmath` docs…)