# fraction inside fraction

Tags: amsmath, fractions

While using \frac gives me smaller characters, \cfrac almost get what I want, except there is quite large space above the denumerator.

I follow [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165933/problem-with-fraction) but right now without the $\displaystyle$ because I do not where I should use that.

```
\begin{equation}
\frac{v_{out}}{i_{in}} = \cfrac{R_{D}} {\left(\cfrac{s}{\cfrac{1}{C_{o}R_{D}}} + 1 \right) 
\left( \cfrac{s}{\cfrac{g_{m}r_{o} + 1}{C_{PD}(R_{D} + r_{0})}} + 1 \right) }
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: Possibly a duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/399482/134574

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, Hi, thanks for the link. I tried and it works. But somehow it produces error as well 'Missing delimiter (. inserted). [}]'. it is just weird that usually, if there is error, the pdf file is not generated.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, the error messages disappear if I do simply use the bracket, without \left or \right. thanks.
I upvoted your post in that link. if you want, you can answer again here so I can close this question.

Answer (score 8):

A possible solution:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, margin=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
\frac{v_{out}}{i_{in}} 
    = \dfrac{R_{D}}{
        \begin{pmatrix}
            \cfrac{s}{\cfrac{1}{C_{o}R_{D}} + 1}\\ 
        \end{pmatrix}
        \begin{pmatrix}
            \cfrac{s}{\cfrac{g_{m}r_{o} + 1}{C_{PD}(R_{D} + r_{0})} + 1}\\ 
        \end{pmatrix}
                }
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Using `\dfrac` instead of `\cfrac` would seem perfectly adequate.

Combining this idea with [@Zarko's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/576335/5001) to encase the large fraction terms in `pmatrix` environments instead of in `\left(` and `\right` wrappers generates the following results:

[image]

The `\cfrac` macro inserts a `\strut`, which has a total height of `\baselineskip`,  in both the numerator and denominator terms. In contrast, `\dfrac` does not insert (typographic) struts by default. In the present case, the influence of the presence of the struts in `\cfrac` is particularly noticeable in the amount of whitespace that's present above the `s` numerator terms.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\dfrac', '\cfrac', and '\text' macros
\begin{document}
\[
\cfrac{\text{with \texttt{\string\cfrac}}}{%
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \cfrac{s}{\cfrac{1}{C_{o}R_{D}} + 1}
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \cfrac{s}{\cfrac{g_{m}r_{o} + 1}{C_{PD}(R_{D} + r_{0})} + 1}
    \end{pmatrix}
}
\quad\text{vs.}\quad
\dfrac{\text{with \texttt{\string\dfrac}}}{%
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \dfrac{s}{\dfrac{1}{C_{o}R_{D}} + 1}
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \dfrac{s}{\dfrac{g_{m}r_{o} + 1}{C_{PD}(R_{D} + r_{0})} + 1}
    \end{pmatrix}
}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This type of question is one I see frequently showing up on the site: how do I write this "ugly" / complicated expression in LaTeX? Usually you can either do as the other answer do, or you can try to split up the expression using words.

I tend to prefer to split up complicated expressions as show below
[image]
However, you should probably change the function f, alpha and beta to something that is more common in your field. Alternatively you could pack it into a single expression
[image]
Which arguably might be the best from both worlds.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\noindent
The ratio is given as
%
\begin{equation}
    \frac{v_{\text{out}}}{i_{\text{in}}}
    = \frac{R_D}{f(\alpha) \cdot f(\beta)}
\end{equation}
%
where 
%
\begin{equation*}
  f(x) = \frac{s}{x + 1}, \quad 
  \alpha = \frac{1}{C_o R_D} \quad \text{and} \quad 
  \beta = \cfrac{g_{m}r_{o} + 1}{C_{PD}(R_{D} + r_{0})}.
\end{equation*}
%
Let $f(x)=s/(x+1)$, then the ratio
$v_{\text{out}}/i_{\text{in}}$ is defined as
%
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{v_{\text{out}}}{i_{\text{in}}}
    = R_D\biggl/\biggl[ f\biggl(\frac{1}{C_o R_D}\biggr)f\biggl(\frac{g_{m}r_{o} + 1}{C_{PD}(R_{D} + r_{0})}\biggr)\biggr].
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```